# Removing URL from displaying in get_the_content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building out my theme and running into an issue where YouTube URLs are showing up in what I'm using as the excerpt. I currently have a conditional that will show a trimmed down content IF there is no excerpt. Here is my template code:

```php
<?php 
  if ( ! has_excerpt() ) { 
    echo wp_trim_words(wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content(), 40 )) ;} 
  else { 
    the_excerpt(); 
  } 
?>
```

In this particular example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od0up.jpg

the post has a YouTube Gutenberg block as it's first block and showing a trimmed and stripped the_content. It's pulling the YouTube URL which I don't want.

Currently on Wordpress 5.1.1 with Understrap framework. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the URL by using preg_replace:

```
$string = "The Third Culture: The Frontline of Global Thinking http://someurl.com/;via @edge";
$regex = "@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@";
echo preg_replace($regex, ' ', $string);
```

So in your case it will be like this:

```
<?php 
if ( ! has_excerpt() ) { 
   $content = wp_trim_words(wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content(), 40 )) ; 
   $regex = "@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@";
   echo preg_replace($regex, ' ', $content);
}else { 
   the_excerpt(); 
} 
?>
```